# Standard curve for real time

Tags: pcr

When performing a standard curve for some new primers to test for fold change, is it necessary to run the standard curve? I mean, in case your experiment has several genotypes for the same ecotype background, with correspondent control and treatments, must I run the standard curves for all this scenarios, or rather may I pick, just to say a random genotype of treated ones, see that it R=0.99 is or higher and efficiency 2? 
It is in order to not to waste material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the standard curve once for each primer pair to determine efficiencies. You can use the efficiency values for any number of replicates with any template.

I think we have somewhat discussed this issue in your [previous post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16035/real-time-pcr-standard-curve?rq=1).

Comment: sorry to disturb but then if i get an efficiency value using control tissue, this values may be used for treatments, isn´t it?

Comment: yep.. the efficiency is just the property of the primer and its template DNA..